# Krovak projection EPSG 5514: Correct data transfer between R and ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, coordinate-system, r, slovakia

I have a problem which many ArcGIS, QGIS and R users from Czech Republic and Slovakia may encounter. In ArcGIS, I am working EPSG: 5514,  Projected Coordinate System, defined as:

```
S-JTSK_Krovak_East_North
WKID: 5514 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Krovak
False_Easting: 0.0
False_Northing: 0.0
Pseudo_Standard_Parallel_1: 78.5
Scale_Factor: 0.9999
Azimuth: 30.28813975277778
Longitude_Of_Center: 24.83333333333333
Latitude_Of_Center: 49.5
X_Scale: -1.0
Y_Scale: 1.0
XY_Plane_Rotation: 90.0
Linear Unit: Meter (1.0)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_S_JTSK
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_S_JTSK
  Spheroid: Bessel_1841
    Semimajor Axis: 6377397.155
    Semiminor Axis: 6356078.962818189
    Inverse Flattening: 299.1528128
```

When I load my file in R, my `proj4string(data_in_5514)` shows:

```
 "+proj=krovak +lat_0=49.5 +lon_0=24.83333333333333 +k=0.9999 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"
```

I've got the same information when I export my files from R using `writeRaster()` function from `raster` package. However, when I want to open my data modified in R again in ArcGIS, my ArcGIS crashes, and if I am lucky, I've got a warning message :

**Warning, inconsistent extent!**

which means (http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37732):

> This error message is returned if the data has an incorrect projection definition.
>
> Specifically, the data is in a projected coordinate system with units of feet, meters or other linear units, but the projection has been defined with a Geographic Coordinate System (GCS) that has units in decimal degrees.

**Thus, obviously the projection of my data has changed, but when and how ???**

How can I correctly transfer data between R and ArcGIS using Krovak EPSG 5514? I've also found, that this one PCS is also listed as EPSG: 102067 under ArcGIS, however, R doesn't recognize this code.

**EDIT :**

sample data: http://ulozto.sk/xNHrBv2D/r3-zip

as an output I was using several formats. I was able to opet Gtiff once, .img neidther one time, .grd seems not to be directly recognized by ArcGIS.

export data:

```
writeRaster(aaa, filename="r3.img", format="HFA", overwrite=TRUE)
# export data
writeRaster(aaa, filename="r3.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
# export data
writeRaster(aaa, filename="r3", overwrite=TRUE)  # creates a .grd
```

Comment: Since `writeRaster` can output to several formats, it would be helpful to know the format you are using, whether you have tried other formats, and see the exact `writeRaster` statement. It would also be helpful to see the workflow (abbreviated if necessary), i.e. loading from disk, the operation (or some operation) that alters the data, and writing to desk.

Comment: Please make your problem is reproducible by providing sample code you have tried so far and/or sample data. If you can not share the original data, use the data that comes with the packages.

Comment: What version of GDAL do you have in R? There were [some improvements for Krovak projections for GDAL 2.0](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5892).

Comment: It is far from perfect but using formats for conversion between the various software which discards datum/projection information completely is also a way to go to overcome this.

Comment: I'd remove projection from output raster and see what happens. You can always define it later in ArcGis

Comment: cool @MikeT my rgdal version is 0.9-2, I'll try to update it !

Comment: the link about krovak projection you have provided just suggest not to use GTiff to store data in Krovak projection, if I've understood it right ?

Comment: Cool @FelixIP it seems that removing the projection in combination with updatingmy packages helped a lot !! thanks ! I may accept it as answer if you will add it here...

Comment: the version of GDAL is `require(rgdal); rgdal::getGDALVersionInfo()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to remove projection information in R output raster and open it in ArcGIS.
If successful, define projection from within latter.

I applied this trick with vectors coming from MapInfo to ESRI products.
Slight difference in projection naming by these two packages had devastating result with points being 200 m away from their true position.
Good example of it is projection called GD_1949_New_Zealand_Map_Grid in ArcGIS.